# Python function to give default value for blank entry not working

Tags: python, function

I have been trying to figure this out for way too long! What to do?

```
def fallBack(submission):
    if (submission == ""):
           submission = "fixed!"  
           return(submission)

name = input("What is your name?")
(fallBack(name))

location = input("Hi "+name+"! Nice to meet you, I live inside a computer, where do you live?")
```

I keep having the last input just print out nothing...

Comment: Test for submission is null rather than empty string.

Comment: You don't store the return value of `fallBack()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the result of `fallBack()`. 
Also, change `fallBack()` to return the original value if it is non-null:

```
def fallBack(submission):
    if not submission:
        return "fixed!"
    else:
        return submission
```

Then, use it like this:

```
name = fallBack(input("What is your name?"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the brackets around `fallBack(name)`

```
def fallBack(submission):
    if (submission == ""):
        submission = "fixed!"  
    return submission

name = input("What is your name?")
name = fallBack(name)

location = input("Hi "+name+"! Nice to meet you, I live inside a computer, where do you live?")
```

Also remember that if using python 2.7 you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: Sorry about that, the down vote was before your edit and my computer restarted before I could leave a comment as to why. I've since removed it.

Comment: On a style note, I would lose the parentheses in the `if` statement. In fact, `if not submission` is also an acceptable (and I would argue more semantic) way of expressing the same thing.

Comment: No problem, I was editing my code when you voted down :) Yes, I can see also different options, but I wanted to make just necessary changes to get it working code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but I think this would do it:

```
def fallBack(submission):
    if (submission == ""):
           submission = "fixed!"  
    return (submission)

name = input("What is your name?")
name = fallBack(name)

location = input("Hi "+name+"! Nice to meet you, I live inside a computer, where do you live?")
```

Your two mistakes were not to return anything in case there is nothing to fix, and not to assin the value returned by the function.

By the way, there is a much more idiomatic way of doing this in Python:

```
name = input("What is your name?")
name = name or 'fixed!'

location = input("Hi "+name+"! Nice to meet you, I live inside a computer, where do you live?")
```

The second line tests if converting `name` to a boolean, and, if it returns `False` (for a string, it is equivalent to testing if it is not empty), replace it with `'fixed!'`

Answer (score 0):

The return is not well aligned! You are not returning anything unless submission is empty!  :-)

```
def fallBack(submission):
    if (submission == ""):
        submission = "fixed!"  
    return(submission)
```